# jQuery - Parsing JSON file on a remote server from javascript on a local file

Tags: jquery, json, file, parsing, jsonp

Okay I've googled this - and found if you view a webpage locally (i.e. File://t:/temp/index.html) it is able to retrieve remotely accessible JSON files - http://api.trademe.co.nz/api/v1/Categories.json

If I save a copy of the file locally, I can parse it perfectly. But attempting to do it from the remote location I get a parser error thrown.

for processing locally I have been using $.getJSON() but for connecting and retrieving from a remote location (the example above) - to use JSONP the jQuery plugin.

But even after following all the examples that are "suppose" to work - It just won't work.

Can someone help me out? Even if could just show me an example of it working on a local page retrieving and parsing the remote JSON file successfully.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it violates the sandbox if you make a JSON request from local to remote. 
What i would do is run the solution through the IIS if your on a PC, this emulates an website and might do the trick.

Follow these instructions:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/28/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for may have already been answered by another question ... [Loading JSON in PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882939/loading-json-in-phonegap)

Basically, you have to register external hosts you want to access in the PhoneGap.plist file.

From [PhoneGap for iOS FAQ](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/41631150/PhoneGap%20for%20iOS%20FAQ)...

> Q. Links to and imported files from external hosts don't load? A. The
>   latest code has the new white-list feature. If you are referencing
>   external hosts, you will have to add the host in PhoneGap.plist under
>   the "ExternalHosts" key. Wildcards are ok. So if you are connecting to
>   "http://phonegap.com", you have to add "phonegap.com" to the list (or
>   use the wildcard "*.phonegap.com" which will match subdomains as
>   well).

Comment: Hey @BlackMael Thanks for the answer. What I'm currently doing is outside of PhoneGap at the moment - but will be introduced to that shortly. I have noticed the same code works perfectly retrieving a remote json file for twitter, but switching URLs to TradeMe threw an error. Running the TradeMe JSON through a parser is showing me basically two things: 1, The data is huge! (800k) and 2, The JSON is slow to respond (which is possibly due to the size!) . I'm going to have to "try" find a way to make the request smaller or add a bigger timeout/find out $.getJSON limits.